# JavaFX: How do I write a KeyEvent handler for movement that isn't in the initial scene?

Tags: java, javafx, keyevent

I'm trying to learn JavaFX by making a Pong game. I want my third scene to have KeyEvents for paddle movement, but everything I find has it in the initial scene and I can't figure out how to utilize it outside of the start function in the initial scene. I currently have three scenes set up with separate controllers. The first (Main) is a splash screen that moves to the second scene (the Menu) on Action.

```
Main.java

@Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        
        //Stage stage1 = new Stage();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);      
        
        Image icon = new Image("pongicon.png");
        stage.getIcons().add(icon);
        stage.setTitle("Pong");

        stage.setResizable(false);
        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

MainController.java
public void switchToScene2(ActionEvent e) throws IOException{
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Menu.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

On the menu are three options: Start, Load, and Quit. When you click start it goes into the third scene (Gameplay).

```
MenuController.java
public class MenuController {
    
    @FXML
    private Circle myCircle;
    private double radius;
    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private Parent root;
    
    public void switchToGameplay(MouseEvent e) throws IOException{
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Gameplay.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void start(MouseEvent e) throws IOException {
        myCircle.setRadius(radius+=1000);
        switchToGameplay(e);
    }
    
    public void load(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Load");
    }
    public void quit(MouseEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    
    
}
```

Obviously I want the player to be able to move their paddle so I tried to set up a KeyEvent like I would a Mouse or Action event with a switch statement and that didn't work. I investigated  and found that  I have to set my scene like this :

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Gameplay.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
Controller controller = loader.getController();
scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
     @Override
     public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
    switch(e.getCode()) {
        case W:
            controller.moveUp();
        break;
        case S:
             controller.moveDown();
        break;
        default:
             break;
        }
    }
});
```

So I attempted to put that in my switchToGamePlay function in MenuController

```
public void switchToGameplay(MouseEvent e) throws IOException{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Gameplay.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Controller controller = loader.getController();
        stage = (Stage)((Node)e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
                switch(e.getCode()) {
                case W:
                    controller.moveUp();
                    break;
                case S:
                    controller.moveDown();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

That didn't work as I get a ModuleLayer error on "controller.moveUp()/moveDown()" so I added it straight to my GameplayController. I'm not even going to put the code for that here because it was just straight up wrong and confused me worse. Sorry if I'm unclear on anything, its my first SO post. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you need to take the time to get familiar with the basic of `JavaFX` and `FXML`. I would suggest starting with [this](https://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-tutorial/). Some things may be different due to the tutorial being old. Have fun!

Comment: @SedJ601 thanks I've been giving it a read and looked at some other resources and I won't lie, I'm still just as confused lol. I'm sure it'll be a bit of a process and I'll get there. Thanks for the well wishes! The fun comes after throwing my mouse across the room a few times though :D

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/sedj601/PongFX/tree/master/src/pongfx) is an app I made four years ago. I don't know how good it is, but maybe you can get some ideas from it.

Comment: I actually wound up figuring it out just a bit ago. I had to pass in the scene to the controller using "controller.setScene(scene);" when calling my method. The way I had it the method initialized the controller but it was just sitting there doing nothing. Then in my gameplay controller i made a setter for Scene and wrote my KeyEvent handler in my initialize method. Worked like a charm. I was just getting confused because everything I read and watched had all of the code in a single file so the scene didn't need to be passed anywhere. I don't like doing that so I caused myself extra work lol

Comment: @SedJ601 Thank you! I was pretty beside myself when I saw my paddle move lol. Now to make an ai paddle that doesn't perfectly mimic the y position of my ball. Cheers!

Comment: @SedJ601 Here's what I wound up with. If you find the time I'd appreciate you checkin it out. It's not perfect mind you, but I'm happy with it as a first project. Also, if you do, mind the volume! lol https://github.com/river-lockhart/Pong

Comment: I went to test it out, but it said you used an `ANT` build. I am not sure how that happened given that `Maven` and `Gradle` are the two recommend builds.

Comment: That's what I get for starting with a video tutorial and not thoroughly researching how best to set up a project. I don't really understand the differences between the frameworks and all that quite yet. I just tried to convert it and broke something so I'll look into that tomorrow. Thanks for trying to look anyway :)

Comment: Do you use and IDE?

Comment: @SedJ601 Yeah I'm using Eclipse for JavaFX. I usually use VSCode but everything I found for JavaFX was either on Eclipse or IntelliJ so I just picked one.

Comment: I just found a video on modular vs non-modular so I'm going to investigate further and will find out what I don't know lol. Unfortunately I haven't yet gotten to the classes that deal with all of this stuff, I'm just trying to be proactive since it's summer. Every day presents new questions and all that

Comment: There is nothing wrong with what you did. I just think the people behind the curtains are pushing `Maven` and `Gradle` to manage projects and are trying to phase out `Ant`. I also believe they are pushing `Modular` over `Non-modular`.  https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: Well I appreciate the direction. At least I know what to expect going forward. I switched to IntelliJ and set up Maven there and resituated my program without breaking it this time. I haven't figured out where to go from here, but it runs if you  package and call the jar file.  https://github.com/river-lockhart/Pong

Comment: My guess is that your latest repo is private. The link leads me to an error page.

Comment: Whoops! Fixed https://github.com/river-lockhart/Pong